# CURL and PHP - keep cookies values for next request

Tags: php, curl

I have following problem - after I send POST request to some page, let's say example.com/search.php I'm getting first page of results and links for another pages which looks like this:

```
example.com/search.php?start=15
```

but query for search is stored in cookies like this:

```
phpbb2mysql_sid 5e9f95bceb61e9634ce3df03123d9446
```

which I save in cookie jar, however when trying to access next page from results it looks like that curl doesn't use the cookies from the first query, but replace them with new ones, so the page I'm trying to open for that search is empty. Here's my code:

```
public function getPage($url)
{
    $cookie_file_path = 'public/userfiles/cookie.txt';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->parent_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $this->parent_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

    if (!empty($this->post)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->post);
    }

    curl_exec($ch);
    //page with the content I want to grab
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    // following request should use cookies from previous, but seems it doesn't
    // cause search results are empty
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $html;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you verify if public/userfiles/cookie.txt is writeable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have my own cookie routine.

I get the HTTP Response Header

Remove Response Header from $html

Then grab the cookies from the Response Header, putting them in an array

Then save the array for the next time they are needed

change `CURLOPT_HEADER` to true

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);


  $html= curl_exec($ch);
  $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
  $requestHeader= substr($html,0,$skip);
  $html = substr($html,$skip);
  $e = 0;
  while(true){
    $s = strpos($requestHeader,'Set-Cookie: ',$e);
    if (!$s){break;}
    $s += 12;
    $e = strpos($requestHeader,';',$s);
    $cookie = substr($requestHeader,$s,$e-$s) ;
    $s = strpos($cookie,'=');
    $key = substr($cookie,0,$s);
    $value = substr($cookie,$s);
    $cookies[$key] = $value;
  }

$fp = fopen('/home/user/public_html/cookies.ser' ,'w');
fwrite($fp,serialize($cookies));
fclose($fp);
```

The retrieve:

```
$cookies= unserialize(file_get_contents('/home/user/public_html/cookies.ser'));

 $cookie = '';
 $show = '';
 $head = '';
 $delim = '';
 foreach ($cookies as $k => $v){
   $cookie .= "$delim$k$v";
   $delim = '; ';
 }

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie );
```

Comment: "I have my own cookie routine." why?

Comment: I use curl a lot.  And have found the cookie jar to be problematic.

Comment: Sometimes the cookies are are added or updated by javaScript.  Then I have to get the cookie values from the HTML. cookie jar will not do that.  A lot of sites use a series of redirects that will mess up the cookie jar.  I have complete control over cookies.  And my code works every time.

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen an issue where js would edit cookies directly.

Comment: I've run in other ways some sites block curl with JS by using JS with window.location to redirect to the real page, and submitting a form with JS to get to the real page.

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong parameters:

instead of using CURLOPT_COOKIE:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie_file_path);
```

use CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
```

There are differences between those two:

> CURLOPT_COOKIE    The contents of the "Cookie: " header to be used in the
>   HTTP request. Note that multiple cookies are separated with a
>   semicolon followed by a space (e.g., "fruit=apple; colour=red")
>
> CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE    The name of the file containing the cookie data.
>   The cookie file can be in Netscape format, or just plain HTTP-style
>   headers dumped into a file. If the name is an empty string, no cookies
>   are loaded, but cookie handling is still enabled.

further explanation is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) on php.net